# Fullscan on other table LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 2 database tables `Companies` (uses InnoDB engine) and `Company_financial_figures` (uses MyISAM engine). Table `Companies` has about 300 000 records, `Company_financial_figures` has 600 000 recodrs. Also Table `Company_financial_figures` has flag that is used in table LEFT JOIN.

Query idea is to select all actual balances for companies (there is a situation when tere is no balance data for that company, but anyway it must be selected, so I have to use LEFT JOIN). It seems to me, that it must select about 300k records from Company_financial_figures table, but not to make Full table scan, like 600k records. And the performance for this query is very slow.

Query is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT comp.id, comp.name, comp.surname, cff.balance FROM companies comp LEFT JOIN company_financial_figures cff ON (cff.company_id = comp.id AND cff.actual = 1)

+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | companies         | index | NULL          | comp_i_i | 2       | NULL | 346908 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | company_finan..   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL | 610364 |             |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

I have index on company_id column, but it doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use an inner join for this, but could you show your query first? Also, how slow are we talking? And what storage engine are you using on the two tables?

Comment: The first one is InnoDB based, second is MyISAM based. And the INNER JOIN is not a solution, because I have to return rows from Companies table anyway.

Comment: Maybe move `AND cff.actual = 1` to the WHERE clause? Or replace DISTINCT by GROUP BY comp.id?

Comment: If I will move `AND cff.actual = 1` to WHERE clause, this will cut down all records from Copmanies table without actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need the `DISTINCT` keyword? `DISTINCT` always slows down your querying because every record has to be considered explicitly for `DISTINCT` comparison. I don't know how MySQL handles this in detail, but in Oracle, you can get horrible execution plans if one of your `DISTINCT` fields is nullable.

But you shouldn't need it, your records are probably distinct anyway, because you select `comp.id` (I'm guessing?) Wouldn't it be a lot faster when you remove `DISTINCT` ?

Comment: I can get rid of DISTINCT, be the Explain plan still the same.

Comment: Too bad... These databases don't behave the same way. What happens if you add an index to `cff.actual` ?

Comment: What about single index of (actual,company_id)

Comment: This solved my problem, I have used coplex INDEX, and now it works great! Thank you!